# Get last known domain user, using mssql db

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to get information about last known domain user how accessed a DB hosted on mssql. The reason being we have a lot of DB's running on old systems which we need to move, but unsure of their usage. manually this would take to much time, so thought that this maybe could be done by code.

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: If you're looking for future logging, you can enable [Login Auditing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx).  If you're looking for logins that have already occurred and Login Auditing was not enabled, then you're very likely out of luck unless you had some application specific or custom logging.

Comment: Thx, the problem is we have 500 DB instances :-) so this would not be possible.

Comment: Hmm, what if maybe instead a script could monitor traffic looking for activity relating SQL and then do a lookup in on that ip address getting dnsname of machine?